# I Want to execute this function as a thread for all the values in List via multi threading please guide me

Tags: java, multithreading, list, arraylist, java-threads

```
List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();for(
String name:listOfNames) {  ///WANT TO PASS THIS VALUE IN THIS FUNCTION AND THIS FUNCTION WILL BE RUN IN PARALLEL FOR ALL INDEXES
   myfunct(name){
  //dosomething
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: "//do something //suppose sysout(name);" if we suppose this, there would be no advantage in multithreading. It would simply print the names in an unpredictable order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple

```
listOfNames.parallelStream().forEach( name -> {
  // do something
});
```

would already do.

The point here is: there are **zillions** of ways doing that, and they are all extensively documented. I suggest you start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) for example. And as [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) correctly stated: "just adding threads" isn't necessarily an improvement. More threads do not automatically mean "better". To the contrary, they make code harder to follow and understand, and open a whole universe of adding potential bugs.

Comment: "simple" in a multithreading question? Lol.

Comment: @AndyTurner Simple in the sense of: the answer reflects the amount of energy that the OP has put into his question. It is meant as a "it can be done with a one-liner, but" guidance.

Comment: I would also add to the "zillions" paragraph that making things multi-threaded doesn't automatically make them *better*. There has to be something parallelizable about the work being done (printing things out *isn't* parallelizable); and you have to take care to make sure that it is safely parallelized; and using `parallelStream()` can lead to contention with other places in the same program also using it. So, to come back to my original comment: it may not be quite so "simple".

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> listOfNames = asList("a", "b", "c");
listOfNames
    .parallelStream()
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

will result in e.g.

> bca

Comment: sir i have multiple executions taking place inside that loop !

Comment: i want a brief answer for this that how i could multiple tasks can be achieved inside that loop

Comment: Note that breaking after the `.` is not conventional in Java. [Sun's style guide](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf#page=9) (on which many subsequent style guides are based) says that you should break before operators: it helps you to see that the new line is a continuation of the previous.

Comment: @saadamin You are very welcome, and thanks for the quick comeback!